# Adding Objects to single Realm File

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm

Before I begin here is a bit a background for you all so your possible answers won't go beyond my comprehension level:
1. I'm only jolt starting to learn swift and is still learning the in and outs of both realm and Xcode.
2. My only OOP experience has been with java, and at that very low.

So here is my issue:

I'm trying to make a single realm file hold an entire list of "user profile" data(ie. name, age, email). I'm attempting to do this by allowing an IBAction button to cause an object to be saved to the realm file as shown below

```
@IBAction func signUpButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let realm = try! Realm()



    try! realm.write {

    user.userName = userNameTextField.text!
    user.passWord = passWordTextField.text!
    user.email = emailTextField.text!
    user.name = fullNameTextField.text!
    user.age = ageTextField.text!

    profile.person.append(user)


    realm.add(profile)

    }
}
```

The only problem here is that it's not adding object but instead updating the one that was created before, can anyone tell me how I can accomplish this using an IBAction Button?

Comment: does your user object have primary key?

Comment: @Tj3n yes, in the object file i have a "id" variable like so : dynamic var id = UUID().uuidString, in the object class with a primary key function that returns the ID. What would you advise?

Comment: What's that `realm.deleteAll` doing in there?

Comment: I put that there to quickly wipe the realm file of any previous data, treat it as its not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an `Object` has already been added to a Realm file, then you can change its properties by opening up a write transaction and simply modifying its properties in there.

```
let realm = try! Realm()

let newUser = User()
newUser.userName = userNameTextField.text!

// Add to Realm for the first time
try! realm.write {
   realm.add(newUser)
}

// Update its property at a later time
try! realm.write {
   newUser.userName = userNameTextField.text!
}
```

It's not necessary to call `realm.add` or `profile.person.append(user)` again if those objects were already previously added.

I'm not sure where `user` and `profile` are coming from in your example code there. Since there's no `let user = User()` inside that method, I'm assuming you're creating single copies of them elsewhere in the view controller class.

If `profile` has already been added to the Realm, you shouldn't be calling `realm.add(profile)` again, as that will add a second copy (And calling `append` each time *probably* won't break, but it's not recommended).

To work out if `profile` is already inside a Realm file, you can check by using `profile.realm != nil`. To check if `user` already belongs in `profile`, you can user Realm's inverse relationships feature.

```
class User: Object {
   dynamic var userName = ""
   dynamic var password = ""
   dynamic var email = ""
   dynamic var name = ""
   dynamic var age = ""

   let profile = LinkingObjects(fromType: Profile.self, property: "person")
}
```

Comment: Accepted as answer, though I've changed my code a bit (eliminated the one to many relationship) in this new question  here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40550384/user-made-from-realm-object-has-same-primary-key-realm

Answer (score 0):

If your object have primary key, you can only add new by fetch then delete it, then add new one, else you can only update it (primary key is used to prevent duplication)

If you want to have 2 object that have similar property value, then just simply remove the primary key from the object class