# User made from Realm object has same Primary Key Realm

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, realm

Im trying to use a real model to make a user profile, here is the model below:

```
class UserProfile: Object {
dynamic var id = UUID().uuidString
dynamic var name:String = ""
dynamic var age = ""
dynamic var email = ""
dynamic var userName = ""
dynamic var passWord = ""

override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "id"
}

}
```

I'm adding objects to the default realm file via an IBAction button as shown here:

```
@IBAction func signUpButton(_ sender: UIButton) {



    try! realm.write {

    user.userName = userNameTextField.text!
    user.passWord = passWordTextField.text!
    user.email = emailTextField.text!
    user.name = fullNameTextField.text!
    user.age = ageTextField.text!
    user.id = UUID().uuidString

    realm.add(user)

    }
    userQuery()
}
```

The issue is that the created user objects have the same "id"/Primary key:

Jane Vergo is 17 years old ID: A6A67E2D-C9A9-4D6B-815C-27BC22B3089B

Jake Lawson is 19 years old ID:  A6A67E2D-C9A9-4D6B-815C-27BC22B3089B

Luke Cage  is 20 years old ID: A6A67E2D-C9A9-4D6B-815C-27BC22B3089B

IS there anyway to make it so that each user has a different primary key/id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realm is an object database, so you need to create a new object every time:

```
try! realm.write {

    user = User() // Create a new user instance

    user.userName = userNameTextField.text!
    user.passWord = passWordTextField.text!
    user.email = emailTextField.text!
    user.name = fullNameTextField.text!
    user.age = ageTextField.text!
    user.id = UUID().uuidString

    realm.add(user)

}
```

Comment: Yes, this works! Though the only issue now is that every user now has the exact same primary key, is there anyway to make it so that each users get a separate unique one?

Comment: What's more is that the Primary key changes everytime.

Comment: It sounds like you have a logic problem. Firstly, Realm won't let you write two separate objects with the same primary key, so I suspect you actually only have one in the database that keeps getting updated. Use the Realm Browser to confirm what you have in the database. Secondly, I assume you're saying if you sign-up the same user more than once you get a different primary key. You would need to check the user being signed up has not already signed up. One option would be to make `userName` the primary key instead of `id`.